# Prevent commit before peer review in svn

Tags: svn, hook

Is there any svn hook for peer review? I would like to make sure that any developer could not commit code until it gets reviewed by a peer. How can this be enforced by svn?

Answer (score 4):

I sense a misunderstanding here: If you are trying to add code review as a pre-check-in step, you are treating your source repository as the authority for perfect, ideal code, but keep imperfect code out of it. This is detrimental to the overall usefulness of a source repository. Code should be in the repository as early as practically possible. Code in the repository is change-tracked, easily accessible, easier to review and easier to backup.

So, go the easy route: Store code in branches (maybe an extra `unreviewed` folder alongside `branches` and `tags`) and review the branch before it gets merged into its target branch. The technical side gets easier, and you have no need for pre-commit hooks.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a code review tool that works with svn. See here for some suggestions: [What's the best way to do a code review with Subversion (SVN)? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99707/whats-the-best-way-to-do-a-code-review-with-subversion-svn)

Also see this very similar question on Quora which has some good answers: [What are the best code review tools?](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-best-code-review-tools)

Comment: The link is sadly dead

Comment: @ymoreau: I've updated my answer with the correct hyperlink.