# SVN code review without branches for SVN

Tags: svn, trac

I'm currently working on a couple projects with some experienced programmers and some amateur programmers. We used to work in a network directory, but we decided to switch to SVN to manage our code.

We would also like to review the code that is committed to the repository before it gets added to production server.
We tried things like Trac, but those either didn't block the code from being added before getting a pass or it wouldn't work without branches. And we can't learn our amateur developers to start using branches.

Does anybody know a system that would work for us?

Many thanks

Comment: Related: [Prevent commit before peer review in svn](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8905931) (but not duplicate)

Comment: Acquire better amateur developers which can be taught to use branches. If you just remove write access to trunk for them, it's swim or drown. And really, it isn't that hard.

Comment: More discussion here: [What's the best way to review a code before it's committed to the trunk? (SVN)](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/144614) does SVN support limiting access to branches? I'm not sure off the top of my head. If it does, perhaps the amateur programmers could be given access only to the branch, eliminating the problem of training. Another idea that comes to mind is a distributed VCS like Git: have a "dirty" repo to which everyone commits; and pull changes manually (after review) to the production repo. But then, Git of course comes with a learning curve

Comment: ... and more interesting stuff when Googling `svn repository review before commit`, in case nothing comes up here

Comment: @Pekka웃: yes, limiting access to branches / any directory is possible.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use software like [ReviewBoard](http://www.reviewboard.org/) to manage your code reviews.  The Review Board project itself does something like this.  If you want to contribute something, you can't commit directly to the repository (write access is restricted to a small group).  You have to check out a copy of the code, make your changes, and submit your changes as a patch for code review.  When the review is complete, one of the Review Board maintainers will download the final patch off of the review request and commit it to the repository.  Contributors can do all of this without needing to create branches or anything like that.

The downside to this approach is that it involves some additional work (somebody has to download and commit the patches).  With some clever scripting, though, you can probably automate most of this process.

A variation of this would be to require trunk commits to indicate a code review ID number (something like `[review 1234]` could work).  Any commits without a code review ID would be rejected by the repository's pre-commit hook script.  That script can also parse out the review ID number, look up that code review in Review Board, and verify that someone has signed off on the change.  If no senior developer has signed off, the script would reject the commit.  This approach allows your developers to do their own commits without requiring a third party to intervene, but it requires a significantly more complicated hook script.