# Integrate Review Board with SVN for commit approval

Tags: svn, review-board

1. User commits from SVN. The change instead if going into repository should go to review board in form of diff(automatically).
2. Review should be assigned to default reviewer(for starters, later may be it can be specified in commit string)
3. Reviewer will review it. On approval that diff should be committed to repository (Automatically or Manually)

Comment: Exactly the same as http://stackoverflow.com/q/21853797/718379

Comment: Ohh yes..Though its same same it doesnt have the code or hook details.. Will you mind to share the hook details / code with me. I have exact above mentioned use case. 
So It would be great if you can share it with me.