# How to approve source commits in SVN

Tags: svn, hook

We have a repository in SVN that many people are working on. Is there a way to approve source on commit?

If not, what other source control systems exist that support this?

Comment: Yes, there is. Have you tried searching the web about this topic?

Comment: @bahrep Can you clarify please... I was under the impression that was no possible.

Comment: @TT. why do you think this is not possible? Use pre-commit hook scripts, code review tools, use branches, whatever.

Comment: @bahrep Yeah sure, branches that was my idea. But is there a way with pre-commit hook to commit to a review stage where it can be allowed/disallowed?

Comment: Github encapsulates this with their fork and/or pull request workflow. It would appear [assembla](http://blog.assembla.com/assemblablog/tabid/12618/bid/92726/Try-the-new-Subversion-code-review-and-merge-requests.aspx) have a tool that supports it for SVN. Generally speaking it's not the source control that supports this feature but the toolchain for that source control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if you can get some useful information in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8905931/243373) on StackOverflow.

What I would do: tell users to commit their changes in a seperate branch. Before merging the branch to your production branch, review the code. Then once the branch has been vetted you can go on with a merge.